# URI remove dot at the end of original url

Tags: c#, .net, uri, webrequest

```
WebRequest.CreateDefault(new Uri("http://localhost/test_Queue."))
```

Do request to http://localhost/test_Queue (without dot)

- replace dot to `%2E` before request not suitable.
- `genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes"` - does not help

any ideas? (solution for 4.0 framework)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the URI parser. You can avoid it using a different method to create the web request.

Use

```
WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://localhost/test_Queue.")
```

instead.

Comment: thanks, CreateHttp will not pass cookies to the server - not suitable and this available since 4.5 (I looking solution for 4.0)

Comment: [CreateHttp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.createhttp(v=vs.100).aspx) is available in .NET 4.0. As for passing cookies, you need to assign a [CookieContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) to the request and you're good to go.